# Recolher dados combinados de um conteúdo com URLs diferentes no Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Ao recolher as informações do Google Analytics para a base de dados local, acabo por consumir múltiplos *requests* para dados referentes ao mesmo artigo no web-site.

Isto ocorreu dada a evolução do mesmo que se reflete também em alterações no URL:

```sh
# Query String
http://www.example.com/?modulo=artigos&amp;chamada=ver&amp;artigo=1

# Slugs
http://www.example.com/artigo/meu-artigo-fixe

# Sub-Domain
http://artigo.example.com/meu-artigo-fixe
```

Tendo cada artigo três URLs, estando cada um no Google Analytics, o código em baixo é executado 3 vezes, uma por cada URL, de forma a se obter a informação desejada:

```
$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

$gaProfileID = 'ga:xxxxxxxx';
$startDate = '2000-01-01';
$endDate = date("Y-m-d", time());
$metrics = 'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:percentNewVisits';
$optParams = array(
    "filters" => "ga:pagePath==/".$urlDoArtigo // multiplas chamadas porque este valor muda
);

$results = $service->data_ga->get($gaProfileID, $startDate, $endDate, $metrics, $optParams);
```

## Pergunta

Como obter os dados de cada URL combinados <sup>(somatório)</sup> numa só chamada ao Google Analytics ?

```
$ga_sessions = 'totalSessõesDosTrêsUrls'
$ga_pageviews = 'totalSessõesDosTrêsUrls'
$ga_percentNewVisits = 'totalPercentagemNovasVisitasDosTrêsUrls'
```

Comment: Você já tentou fazer `"filters" => "ga:pagePath==/{$urlDoArtigo1};ga:pagePath==/{$urlDoArtigo2}"`? onde o `;` é o [operador AND](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#combiningFilters).

Comment: @qmechanik Estive a ler um artigo sobre isso na semana passada, inclusivé uma resposta no SOEN que sugeria isso, mas ainda não tive oportunidade de realizar testes para apurar o resultado e/ou implicações. Logo que tenha testado volto aqui para informar e deixar os links relevantes.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na [documentação do Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events), tem uma maneira de você capturar eventos.